# how do I represent an input tensor with multiple data types?

Tags: tensorflow

I have so far only used tensor flow with an input tensor that was of all one data type, for example, all float32.

I now want to have an input which can be represented as a table where the rows and column are such:

```
        column0    column1    column2    column3    ...    columnN
person0   CATX      FLOAT       FLOAT      CAT0
person1   CATY      FLOAT       FLOAT      CAT1
person2   CATZ      FLOAT       FLOAT      CAT2
  .
  .
  .
personN   CATAA      FLOAT       FLOAT      CAT00
```

a mixture fo floats and categorical values that I would like one hot encode. CAT is a placeholder for strings that are drawn from a restricted domain of values such as, say, the unique identifiers of machine parts. all the categorical columns are like this.
How do I create an input tensor from these sorts of mixed inputs? Is it possible to do the one hot encodings this way as well?

Comment: Be careful, the title and the body of the question are ambiguous.. If the question is whether a tensor can hold data of multiple different types, the answer is no. If it's whether you can turn a category into a one-hot vector, then that is indeed possible. Is `CAT` an integer or some sort of textual identifier?

Comment: @E_net4 no `CAT` just means that column is a categorical variable. `FLOAT` means that column is all floats. I am indeed specifically asking how to handle this case of mixed categorical variables and floats. I am presently aware of how o do one hot encodings but it isn't clear to me how to have a variety of inputs in addition to one hot encoded values.

Comment: Fine, but how is that categorical variable represented? Also note that a one-hot vector is in fact a vector of floats, and you can concatenate them together.

Comment: @E_net4 the categorical variables are all represented by strings. the strings are drawn from a restricted domain of values such as, say, the unique identifiers of machine parts. all the categorical columns are like this. is that what you mean by "represented" ?

Comment: Well, yes, that is clearer. Please include that in your question, along with a small sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this statement [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor):

> As with normal Tensors, the values in a RaggedTensor must all have the
> same type

Unfortunately, I don't think that you can have mixed types in a Tensor.

If you try something like this:

```
tf.constant([1,'test'])
```

You get the error: *ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with mixed types to Tensor.*

You should find a workaround, maybe create a tensor with strings and cast when needed.